# Conditional Formatting Data Bars Excel - Values less than a target

Tags: excel, ms-office, conditional-formatting

I am wondering if I can achieve the following on Excel:

I have an target value, ex. 50 and I want to add a Data bar at a cell, where if the value of the cell is 50, then the data bar is not shown,if the value of the cell is 49.5, then the data bar is half full, and if the value of the cell is 49, then the data bar is full.

Is it possible to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Thanasis

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the result required is like this:

[image: CF data bars example]

Select A1:A20 and add blue 'standard' Fill and blue Solid Fill Data Bars. In  Manage Rules..., Edit Rule... for Type: select Number for both Minimum and Maximum and Value: 49 and 49.99 respectively. Use Solid Fill and white for Color for Fill and No Border for Border. Set Bar Direction: Right-to-Left, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Then add a new rule with *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=OR(A1<49,A1>49.99,A1="""")
```

Format..., select white for Fill and Grey Outline for Border <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>Apply</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.